# Addition function injective?

Tags: functions

I am just curious to know if addition of two numbers an injective function?

Lets say $\operatorname{Sum}(a,b) = a + b$

Now is the $\operatorname{Sum}$ function an injective functions?

Comment: Since this is homework, what have you tried?

Comment: Is there a difference between `?`, `??` and `???` in your question?

Comment: I really don't know how to proceed with this... The questions is much more complicated that this... so...

Comment: For any **fixed** $b$, the function $g(x)=f(x,b)$ is injective, similarly for any fixed $a$, the function $h(y)=f(a,y)$ is injective, but the function $f(x,y)$ of two variables is not injective.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not, because $2+2=1+3$.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be contratrian and argue that it is injective.  Consider the "curried" addition function $+ : \mathbb N \to (\mathbb N\to \mathbb N)$.  For example, $+(7)$ is the function which maps each number $n$ to $n+7$, and $+(0)$ is the identity function.  Then $+$ is injective because there are no distinct $a, b$ for which $+(a)$ and $+(b)$ are the same function: for every $a\ne b$, there exists a $c$ such that $+(a)(c)\ne +(b)(c)$; in fact, $c=0$ will do for any choice of $a$ and $b$.

I cheerfully invite downvotes, and encourage the original poster to ignore this answer.

Comment: Rather than be contrarian, why not be thorough and mention all three things the question could have meant? (e.g. the function you mention is injective, the function $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is not, and each of the various functions "+a" are injective) Or at least phrase it as "when the question is interpreted *this* way, then *that* is true"?

Comment: The OP defines a function $\mathrm{Sum}$ and asks explicitly about that function, which is clearly $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: actually MJD, you are correct... 
And I guess that i have partly understood your approach

Comment: @hurkyl: because Emanuele had already given a perfectly clear explanation of those points, and I felt that engaging them myself would only detract from that perfect clarity.